# Getting Desktop path with different system languages

Tags: vala

Hi
I would like to know if something like

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

exists for vala. Or how can I get the Desktop path considering different system languages?

Thanks

Comment: What operating system is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Environment.get_user_special_dir`](http://valadoc.org/references/glib-2.0/0.11.5/GLib.Environment.get_user_special_dir.html)`(`[`UserDirectory.DESKTOP`](http://valadoc.org/references/glib-2.0/0.11.5/GLib.UserDirectory.html)`)`.

Comment: Problem, how can I then extract the Desktop's path?
The name given to it changes with the locale..